# C redirect standard output to several places

Tags: c, linux, stdout, io-redirection, tee

It is rather easy to redirect output to another destination. I can easily achieve that with:

```
freopen ("/def/tty0", "w", stdout);
printf ("Redirected");
fclose (stdout);
```

But how could I redirect it to two or more files? I need functionality similar to this provided by "tee".

Is there any well known approach?

Comment: No, you have to manually code it.

Comment: The `tee` command does it by having two files: Standard output and the other file, and writes all input to both those files. That's all `tee` does.

Comment: The well known approach is tee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible to do directly: Each file descriptor is assigned to exactly one resource (typically a file). If you want a write to a `FILE` yield in writes to multiple files, you have to do some tricks. Here are some ideas:

- Use the GNU-only function `fopencookie(3)` to make a `FILE*` that actually outputs to more than one file. See the manpage of `fopencookie(3)` for more details.
- Make a pipe, then fork. The forked process reads from the pipe and writes what it reads into all the files you want. The original process writes to the pipe.
- Invoke `tee(1)` with suitable arguments and write the data to the standard input of `tee(1)`. Have a look at `popen(3)` for a useful function to do that.